# Unable to get SSID of Wifi ios 12

Tags: ios, wifi, ios12, swift4.2

I am unable to get wifi SSID (unique key for wifi). I have seen many answers but nothing works for me .

Most common answer I found was to enable ,In Xcode, under

> Targets -> Capabilities -> **Access WiFi Information** -> Enable it to
>   ON

My Xcode version is **10.1** ,There is no option there  for **Access WiFi Information** .So i turned on **Wireless Accessory Configuration**

**My code is**

```
extension UIDevice {

    public var SSID: String?{
        get {
            guard let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as? [String] else { return nil }
            let key = kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String
            for interface in interfaces {
                guard let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as CFString) as NSDictionary? else { continue }
                return interfaceInfo[key] as? String
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

My swift version is 4.2 and build target version is 12.1 . I am very new to IOS development .Please let me know ,what I am doing Wrong .How can i make it right .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Xcode version is 10.1 ,There is no option there for Access WiFi Information

Then there is something wrong either with your Xcode project, Xcode or your developer profile...

[image: WiFi]

Make sure your project is update-to-date with the latest Xcode configuration (usually, I just build the project and check the warnings)

> I dont have app-store account ,I just created new apple ID

As listed under [Choosing a Membership/Benefits and resources](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/), "Advanced App Capabilities" is not available to "Sign in with Apple ID" (or free developer accounts), this may explain why "Access WiFi Information" is not available to you

Comment: Thanks for replying .  I have checked the Xcode version  it is same as yours  .not getting any warning about this  also i have created new project , Access WiFi Information is not there

Comment: Do you have a paid developer account?

Comment: downloaded this xcode from appstore 2 weeks ago .. I dont have app-store account ,I just created new apple ID

Comment: So you don’t have a paid developer account then? This might be a restriction of the free accounts. You could login into developer.apple.com and check the app entitlements listed under identifiers -> App IDs

Comment: Thanks man you are right ,To have ssid info you need to have paid developer account

Answer (score 1):

After enable `Wireless Accessory Configuration`, Xcode generates the `entitlements` which include `Wireless Accessory Configuration` in your project.

print your `interfaces`, it should include `en0`

`CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo` api description as follows:

`Important`

> To use this function in iOS 12 and later, enable the Access WiFi Information capability for your app in Xcode. When you enable this capability, Xcode automatically adds the Access WiFi Information entitlement to your entitlements file and App ID.

mine works fine, make sure you have wifi connection on your `iphone`, not `simulator`.

Comment: I did print interface its include en0 , is  SSID = en0 ?

Comment: debug the `for interface in interfaces` step by step, does CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo return a dictionary? mine as follows:    3 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : SSIDDATA
    - value : <71697969 2d707269 76617465 2d706b69 28354729>
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : BSSID
    - value : 74:ea:cb:d7:8c:2
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - key : SSID
    - value : qiyi-private-pki(5G)

Comment: No its does not return as dictionary  :

Comment: does your iphone have connected a valid wifi?

Comment: its connected to my imac sharing wifi

Comment: werid, Is your project cotains `xxx.entitlements`,  the key `Wireless Accessory Configuration` exists and enable `true`

Comment: I have also checked with valid wifi ,Its same  problem ,Is your code is same as  mine

Comment: its contains xxx.entitlements and the key contains Wireless Accessory Configuration    is yes

Comment: under Targets -> Capabilities -> Wireless Accessory Configuration, is there three steps and all steps are marked right?

Comment: hhahahha Thanks  >> :)

Comment: Are you using  paid developer account ?\

Comment: I need favour can you send me sample working code for wifi name :) may be something is missing that i am unable to find

Comment: Thanks man for help .My problem is resolved by using paid developer account